# get values from ng-model array in an tags

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I need help with getting values from array into comma separated list.

https://jsfiddle.net/V4BqE/167/

I have input tag:

```
 <input type="number" ng-model="data.price1[$index]" ng-change="pricecalc1($index)" placeholder="Enter Product Price">
```

Like this i have array of inputs

my js is : When i alert the model value ($scope.data.price1) i got the array of inputs like `{"0":"1000","1":"500"}`

Where 1000,500 are input values

Upto this everything is fine but how can i split the values only, not the index
Expected output : `{1000,500}`

Any help will be highly appreciable 
Thank You

Comment: `{1000 , 500}` is not a valid JavaScript object. Also your Fiddle throws a lot of errors when entering something in the input fields, you might want to check those first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the data stored to array you need to define that array. Otherwise `ng-model` is gong to assign to an object as it is currently doing

Change

```
 $scope.data={};
```

To

```
 $scope.data={price1:[]};
```

Comment: is it possible to add a name before each value like this                  $scope.data = {
            [{price1: "aaa"}, {price1:"bbb"}, {price1:"ccc"}]
 }   or    $scope.data = {
            ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
        }

Comment: sure just push those items into array when you receive them

Comment: i need to insert dynamically and i used this  $scope.data={price1:[]}; so every time if i add a value it pushes like this $scope.data = { ["aaa, bbb, "ccc"] } .how to change this like  $scope.data = { ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] }

Comment: Need to see code/data source for that. Suggest you start another question